# I want to generate a sequence using JavaScript to such that for a given value , i want to increment 30time, the sequence will be based on 4% increase

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, sequence

I want to generate a sequence using JavaScript to such that for a given value , i want to increment 30time, the sequence will be based on 4% increase, below is the code that I have tried

```
    var yearStart = 500;
    var y = yearStart;
    
    var limit =  yearStart + 30;
    
    var arr = [];
    
    for (var i = y; i <= limit; 1.04*i++) {
    
     arr.push(i);
    console.log(i++);
    }
```

my result is below

> 524
> 526
> 528
> 530
> Array [500, 502, 504, 506, 508, 510, 512, 514, 516, 518, 520, 522, 524, 526, 528, 530]

Comment: You should not do `i++` in console.log, if you are using it just for logging, as `i++` will change value of `i` variable.

Comment: can you explain what do you mean about 4% increase? and what output do you expect?